# Php - Mysql default to NULL while inserting data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into a `MySql` database with the query below.

```
$sqlQuery = "insert into abc set a='$var1', b=STR_TO_DATE('$b', '%d/%m/%Y')"
```

I get this error

> Incorrect datetime value: '' for function `str_to_date()`

How can I default both `a` and `b` to `NULL` when the variable values are missing.

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use prepared statements, rather than concatenating variables into your query. Simply escaping your variables is not enough. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: Are those fields nullable? You can set the `default` values of `a` and `b` to null in MySQL, then only supply those fields when executing the query in PHP.

Comment: thanks @EdCottrell you have rightly suggested, I am basically fond of ORMs like hibernate and sql-Alchemy but very new to PHP

Comment: @Qirel yes the fields are by default NULL, but I have multiple columns and would have to check using separate conditions to only run query when they are not null, I would rather have query handle it by self.

Comment: Given your past experience with hibernate etc., take a look at [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/index.html)

Comment: Also, the basic mysql date compatible string is of the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.  If you pass your strings in in that format there is no need to run mysql conversion functions.  With that said -- for php, if you aren't going to use Doctrine, then use PDO and read @EdCottrell link.  It's bad coding not to.  Also the answer from esnkrimi is pertinent because `SET=` is the format you use for updates, not insert.

Comment: Also, before people complain, yes you can use SET=, but like many mysql specific things, just because you can doesn't mean you should.  Use the ANSI standard form.

Comment: :) I get you, I am taking all these suggestions and would be utilizing them for new scripts, for now, I need to do some quick dirty bug fix :P and this format code is everywhere

Answer (score 1):

If the columns are null by default, you can omit them in the `INSERT` query if the values are empty. Generate the query dynamically using an array, and implode on it within your query. The keys represent the column-names, the value of the element in the array is the value to be inserted.

```
$columns = [];

if (!empty($var1)) {
    $columns['a'] = $var1;
}
if (!empty($var2)) {
    $columns['b'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($var2));
}

if (!empty($columns)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO abc (".implode(", ", array_keys($columns)).") 
                     VALUES (".implode(", ", array_values($columns)).")";
}
```

If you can tell which database-API you're using (MySQLi or PDO), I can show you how to dynamically create the prepared statement instead, **which you really should use**! See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

**Update: Using prepared statements with MySQLi**
MySQLi bindings are ordered, and using placeholders as `?`. You still generate the values in `$columns` as before, but the generation of the query is slightly different.

- Use `trim(str_repeat("?, ", count($columns)), ", ")` to generate the placeholders.
- Use `str_repeat("s", count($columns))` to generate the types.
- Use the "unpacking operator" `...` to unpack all the values.

The below code assumes that the connection-object is called `$mysqli`.

```
if (!empty($columns)) {
    $column_list = implode(", ", array_keys($columns));
    $bindings_list = trim(str_repeat("?, ", count($columns)), ", ");
    $types_list = str_repeat("s", count($columns));

    $query = "INSERT INTO abc ($column_list)
                     VALUES ($bindings_list)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param($types_list, ...$columns);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: I am using MySQLi

Comment: I've revised my answer to show how you can dynamically create the query using a prepared statement with MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

Set default value of these columns in your database as NULL so when these values is missing then NULL with automatically saved as default.

Comment: they already default to NULL but if the value is missing it does the error

Comment: So Use conditional statement like: $var1 ? $var1 : NULL;

Answer (score -1):

Don't Get MySQL to change the date format. Do it by your PHP code and make sure that SQL injection is handled.

```
$a = $_POST['var1'] ?? null;
$b = $_POST['var2'] ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['var2'])) : null;
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_database', 'your_username', 'your_password');
    $query_obj = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO abc (a, b) VALUES (:a, :b)");
    $query_obj->execute([':a' => $a, ':b' => $b]);
    echo "Data inserted successfully!";
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your code - and don't give MySQL a chance to perform SQL injections....

Answer (score -1):

You should use the format

month / day / year:

```
$sqlQuery = "Insert into abc(a,b) values($var1',STR_TO_DATE('$b', '%m/%d/%Y')"
```

Comment: Always include an explanation with your answer. Why would this code work? What did you change, and why did you change it?

Comment: standard SQL date format is *year-month-day*. Having day in the middle is nonesensical.

Comment: my question is different I am not looking for date formats but setting NULL